# checkout status of a onedrive file using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to check wether a onedrive file has been checked out using microsoft-graph. According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem , there is a publication property of a DriveItem. But this property is not returned by default. But the documentation does not mention how to retrieve this property.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some sample code showing how you're calling the API and the results you _are_ getting will help the community understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you review the [Use query parameters to customize responses](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters) documentation page.  You can use `$select` to choose which properties are returned in the API response.

I believe your query would look something like:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{ITEM ID}?$select=publication`

You can try this query in the Graph explorer with our demo account at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/drive/items/01BYE5RZ6QN3ZWBTUFOFD3GSPGOHDJD36K?$select=publication&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com

Comment: it returns the `level` and `versionId`. Is there an option how to get the information about the user who did the checkout operation? note that the `lastModifiedBy` isn't the right choice. any thoughts?