# Graph API query - how to combine expand and select

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, xamarin.uwp

I have the following working code, that lists all files in a Sharepoint site and also grabs their driveItem details:

```
        var directoryContents = await App.GraphClient.Sites[SiteIdShortName].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId]
            .Items
            .Request()
            .Expand(item => item.DriveItem)
            .GetAsync();
        SharedDocumentList.ItemsSource = directoryContents.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

Now I need a way to also grab the publication status for each item, in additional to the data the above query is already getting.  I found this post here on stackoverflow:

[checkout status of a onedrive file using microsoft graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747778/checkout-status-of-a-onedrive-file-using-microsoft-graph-api)

So I've tried to change my code to look like this:

```
        var directoryContents = await App.GraphClient.Sites[SiteIdShortName].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId]
            .Items
            .Request()
            .Expand(item => item.DriveItem)
            .Select(item => item.DriveItem.Publication)
            .GetAsync();
        SharedDocumentList.ItemsSource = directoryContents.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> Message=Anonymous type in lambda expression may only be initialized
> with direct members of type ListItem Parameter name: selectExpression
> Source=Microsoft.Graph

EDIT 1

I also tried this:

```
        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
        {
            new QueryOption("select", "publication")
        };

        var directoryContents = await App.GraphClient.Sites[SiteIdShortName].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId]
            .Items
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .Expand(item => item.DriveItem)
            .GetAsync();
        SharedDocumentList.ItemsSource = directoryContents.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

But the error I get is:

> Inner Exception 1: JsonReaderException: '{' is invalid after a value.
> Expected either ',', '}', or ']'. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine:
> 223.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. In `Expand` I've specified the property to be expanded with `select` statement which specified property inside the `driveItem`

```
var directoryContents = await App.GraphClient.Sites[SiteIdShortName].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId]
        .Items
        .Request()
        .Expand("driveItem($select=publication)")
        .GetAsync();
SharedDocumentList.ItemsSource = directoryContents.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

Comment: So that works in the sense that it returns the publication data, but it excludes everything else under driveItem.  I need to get everything under the driveITem object, including the publication data, which seems to be null by default.

Comment: @dot in that case you have to specify all properties you need in $select statement.

Comment: kk, just comma values it seems.  Thanks